# Mysterious C:\Syst61705157 folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

I was just running the antivirus on my computer, and noticed it was scanning a folder title Syst61705157 located in the C: drive. I went to open this folder, and it appears to be a very skeletal installation of windows. I cannot open any files because I do not seem to have permission to do so. A search of the registry shows some entries for the friendly names for things like regedit and notepad, a explorer typed path, and a Mount Path (intrestingly, in that same folder is lisked a key WIM Path that is Y:\Recovery\windowsre\WinRE.wim)

My only guess is somehow a recovery partition that I deleted ended up in C:, but I did not delete any partitions until around a week after the date modified date.

So what is this, and can I safely delete it?

[image]

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  Your conclusion is correct, it appears to be a renamed instance of Windows.old, numerous ways this could have happen if you were using OEM software.

Comment: Sorry, I am not that good at making a question clear, I have edited it to clarify.

Comment: You should take ownership of the folder and the files contained within it, verify there is nothing you need, then delete it.